# fancybox not working after ajax partial view load

Tags: javascript, razor

we are using javascript code to load more event on photo gallery, and on each thumb click we are opening the gallery in fancybox. initial load thumbs is working with fancybox. but after load more button click we are returning partial view from controller and AJAX and when we are click on new thumb to open the gallery its open in blank new tab like href. kindly let us know the issue, we are giving the code here. Any help appreciated.

```
<link href="/css/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/photo-gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   

<section id="p-tab-item-1">
    @Html.Partial("PhotoGalleryList", new ViewDataDictionary { {"CatParameter", "Gujarati" }})
</section>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="load-more-btn" onClick="LoadMore()" id="loadMoreBtnG">See More....</a>
```

@* Load more coding*@

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$("input[id=p-tab-1]").click(function () {
        pageIndx = 1;
      if (Gtabflg == false) {
        $("#loadMoreBtnG").show();  
        loadImage('@CurrentPage.Id', 'Gujarati', pageIndx)
      }
      $("#loadMoreBtnE").hide();
        Gtabflg = true;
       Etabflg = false;
    });
});

//Initial Image load
function loadImage(pageNo, thumbType, pageIndx) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/umbraco/surface/Controller/GalleryImages/",
        dataType: "html",

        data: { pgParam: pageNo, catparam: thumbType, index: pageIndx },
        success: function (data) {

            if (thumbType == "Gujarati") {

                $('#p-tab-item-1').html(data);
            } 
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}


function LoadMore(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/umbraco/surface/Controller/GalleryImages/",
        dataType: "html",

        data: { pgParam: pageNo, catparam: thumbType, index: pageIndx },
        success: function (data) {

            if (thumbType == "Gujarati") {
                $('#p-tab-item-1').append(data);
                if (pageIndx == gujmax) {
                    $("#loadMoreBtnG").hide();
                }

            } 
            }

        },
        error: function (result) {
           console.log(result);
           alert(result);
       }
    });

}

$('#imgGallery').click(function(){

    $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'over'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

// thumb click load lightbox image

```
function GetImages(nodeid){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",          
        url: "/umbraco/surface/Controller/GetImages/",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { imgParam: nodeid },
        success: function (result) {

            $('#imgGallery').html('');
            $('#imgGallery').html(result);

            $( "#imgGallery" ).click();
            $( "#imgGallery a:first" ).click();

        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            alert(result);
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

}

partial view code:

@item.GetPropertyValue("title")

GalleryImage view code:

Comment: <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="@item1.Name" href="@j.Url" style="display:none;" title="@j.Caption" >
                   <img src="@j.Url" alt="image"  style="width:200px; height:80px; position: fixed;"/>
                  </a>

Comment: partial view code

Comment: <div >
                            <a rel="@item.Name" href="javascript:void(0);" title="@item.Name" onclick="GetImages(@item.Id);" class="fancybox-thumb">
                                 <img src="@thumb.Url" alt="@item.Name"/>
                                  <div class="thumb-title">
                                     <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GetImages(@item.Id);" class="fancybox-thumb">@item.GetPropertyValue("title")</a>
                                  </div>
                             </a>